# ListView in UWP has unexpected behavior when INotifyCollectionChanged reports bulk changes

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm trying to create a custom collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and reports bulk changes to the internal list of items over time. This is part of a bigger project but I've managed to create a sample app to demonstrate this issue. Please follow the steps below and the explanation is at the end:

1) Open visual studio 2015 and create a Blank Universal Windows app using Build 14393 and call it "SampleApp" so we have the same namespace.

2) Copy the following code to `Main.xaml`

```
<Page x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:SampleApp"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" Margin="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

3) Copy the following code to `Main.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public FakeCollection Items { get; } = new FakeCollection();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Items.Begin();
        }
    }

    public class FakeCollection : List<string>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public async Task Begin()
        {
            var set1 = CreateSet(1, 10);
            var set2 = CreateSet(11, 15);

            AddRange(set1);

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, set1, 0));


            await Task.Delay(2000);

            InsertRange(5, set2);

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, set2, 5));
        }

        public List<string> CreateSet(int start, int end)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();

            for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                list.Add($"Item {i}");
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

The `FakeCollection` is just a `List<string>` and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. It is used in the `ListView` binding in xaml.

When the Main page loads, the `Begin()` method is called and it simply creates a list of strings called "Item 1", "Item 2", ... "Item 10", adds them to the list and then notifies a collection change on all 10 items. This works fine.

However, after waiting 2 seconds, another set is created "Item 11", "Item 12", ... "Item 15", and they are inserted at index 5. We report the collection change again at position 5 with the new set of strings.

I would expect the `ListView` to show the exact order found in the internal collection of `FakeCollection`, which is:

**Item 1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,6,7,8,9,10**

Instead it shows up as

**Item 1,2,3,4,5,11,6,7,8,9,10,7,8,9,10** ????

What happened here? It looks like it added the first item from the raised event and then just repeated the last four!

Is there a trick to making `ListView` work with bulk collection changes?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! Looks like `CollectionChanged` doesn't work when you try to add multiple items at once. I guess you will have to do something like this -

```
for (var i = 0; i < set2.Count; i++)
{
    CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, set2, i + 5));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would just turn it into a standard `ObservableCollection<T>`. Not ideal. Will report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Actually looks like it's been like this since WPF. Don't think they will change the behavior.